# Assign a random avatar to every user?

Tags: avatar, gravatar

I have 10k users on my site and only around 1k of them are using custom avatars (through a shortcode avatar upload I have).

The rest are using a default (and custom) singular gravatar image.

I want to try assign all of the remaining users with a random avatar from my server.

I've tried two methods for this:

```
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'wpb_new_gravatar' );

function wpb_new_gravatar ($avatar_defaults) {
    $myavatar = 'https://example.net/avatars/avatar%20%28'.rand( 1 , 411 ).'%29.png';
    $avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Random Site Gravatar";
    return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

This obviously won't work as it just randomly picks an avatar from my destination and sets that avatar for every user.

Then there is this method:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_avatar_default', 'random_default_avatar' );

function random_default_avatar ( $value ) {
    return 'https://example.net/avatars/avatar%20%28'.rand( 1 , 411 ).'%29.png';
}
```

This will assign a random avatar to them but it will continually do it.

Would there be a way where I can randomly assign an avatar, set it permanently and then move on from that user?

Comment: Where are avatars stored / how can you get/set them?

Comment: The avatars are stored on the root of directory in a folder called "avatars". I was setting them through the two methods above but none of them suit my needs. The closest I've come is method 2 but this will constantly re-apply a random avatar to every user. I'm unsure if a random one can be permanently set through a wordpress hook.

Comment: What you're doing is instead of retrieving an avatar, you get a random one. This is not the same as setting. Which plugin are you using? You probably need to populate one entry in the postmeta table with the proper key and value

Comment: I'm not using a plugin. I'm adding the above code to my themes functions.php file. I'm basically trying to emulate the avatar systems such as "Retro (Generated)" and "MonsterID (Generated)" found in Settings -> Discussion in WordPress but instead of generating them, I already have a list of avatars in a folder. So I wanted to be able select it from "Discussion" and then a random avatar is set for each profile. I hope that clears it up a bit!